# Apache POI generating document and sorting inside

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to '*group*' my transactions by a 'transactionBatch' parameter. I see that my HashMap is successful in gathering unique batches. When I debug the below code everything seems to be done correctly. Although when I check the excel file, transactions are not grouped accordingly. They should be grouped:

```
batch # 1:
- transaction with batch # 1
- transaction with batch # 1

batch # 2:
- transaction with batch # 2
- transaction with batch # 2
```

The result excel file contains:

```
batch # 1:
- transaction with batch # 1
- transaction with batch # 2

batch # 2:
- transaction with batch # 4
- transaction with batch # 1
```

This is the code:

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            hashMap.put(((Element) (nodeList.item(i))).getElementsByTagName("transactionBatch").item(0)
                    .getFirstChild().getNodeValue(), ((Element) (nodeList.item(i))).getElementsByTagName("transactionBatchDate").item(0)
                    .getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                String transactionBatch = ((Element) (nodeList.item(i))).getElementsByTagName("transactionBatch").item(0)
                        .getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                String key = entry.getKey();
                if (transactionBatch.equals(key)) {
                    HSSFRow dynamicRow = spreadSheet.createRow(i + 2);

                    if (nodeList.getLength() != 0) {
                        cell = dynamicRow.createCell((short) 0);
                        cell.setCellValue(((Element) (nodeList.item(i))).getElementsByTagName("transactionNumber").item(0)
                                .getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                        cell.setCellStyle(styleWithDataCentered);

                        ...

                        cell = dynamicRow.createCell((short) 8);
                        cell.setCellValue(((Element) (nodeList.item(i))).getElementsByTagName("transactionBatch").item(0)
                                .getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                        cell.setCellStyle(styleWithDataCentered);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line:

```
HSSFRow dynamicRow = spreadSheet.createRow(i + 2);
```

I had to assign another variable outside of the for method to keep a int:

```
int rowNumber = 2;
```

and then just increase its value with each row.

```
HSSFRow dynamicRow = spreadSheet.createRow(rowNumber += 1);
```